# How to turn an attribute to an integer output with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to use a custom attribute as float/integer output, is that somehow possible? e.g. drive the radius of a Circle by an attribute.

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean a custom property on an object ? I think we won't be able to do it until they add the possibility to refer to object container properties, like the Attribute node in the shader editor where you can choose between geometry / object / instancer. You can do it with a driver but it won't automatically be linked to new or duplicated objects

Comment: @Gorgious: yes, i meant this! Yes, i hoped for something like this "Attribute node" in shader nodes. I thought/hoped this would be easy to implement ;)

Comment: `Named Attribute`? ...or did I misunderstand the question?